# TYPO3: how to migrate $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->quoteStr() for Doctrine insert()

Tags: doctrine-orm, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

In the past, I used `quoteStr()` to sanitize input data before inserting it into the database with `exec_INSERTquery()` e.g. like this:

```php
'info' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->quoteStr($info, 'tx_mytablename')
```

What is the proper way to sanitize input data (strings) for usage with Doctrine in TYPO3 8 and above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your use-case, the following functions provided by Doctrine can (**should!**) be used to sanitize data in SQL queries:

- `createNamedParameter()`
- `quoteIdentifier()`
- `quoteIdentifiers()`

Further details are available in the [TYPO3 documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html) (section "QueryBuilder").

The following code example demonstrates how to apply `createNamedParameter()` for the integer value named `$customerNumber`.

```php
$query = $queryBuilder
  ->select('username', 'customerNumber')
  ->from('fe_users')
  ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
    'customerNumber',
    $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($customerNumber, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
  ))
  ->execute();
```

Comment: keeps to mention that some old code might use an outdated notation for the type like used in `\PDO::_TYPE_`. So it's advised to look up the new [constants of PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php).

Comment: Form of the old notation was `PDO_PARAM_BOOL` used up to PHP 5.0.

Comment: Thx for your explanation but it's mainly targeted for select queries. My question was more about the insert() and I've found what I was looking for in the documentation link: "->values() expects an array of key/value pairs. Both keys (field names / identifiers) and values are automatically quoted. In rare cases, quoting of values can be turned off by setting the second argument to false. In those cases the quoting has to be done manually, typically by using ->createNamedParameter() on the values, use with care …"